# Aggregate by multiple columns, sum one column and keep other columns? Create new column based on aggregated values?

Tags: r, aggregate, grouping

I have a dataframe with sales. I need to aggregate the df by 2 columns `ProductID` and `Day` and sum the values of each aggregated group from a different column `Amount` so that it now shows the total. I wish to keep the other columns that can be grouped as well (same values across rows), in this case just `Product`. The final column `Store` won't be kept, since values can vary within grouped rows. However, I need to add a column `UniqueStores`, which counts the amount of unique stores for each group of same ProductID and Day. For example, the first group with ID=1 and Day= Monday would have 1 unique store "N", so value would be 1.

I tried drafting the table here in text but I couldn't format it correctly, so here as an image of how it looks before aggregating:

[image: Table view]

I've tried aggregating with both group_by + summarise and df[,sum,by] but they don't keep the variables that aren't given as indexes. Is there a workaround without having to manually insert every column that shall remain?

[image: Final View]

Thanks in advance and I hope I made myself clear.

Input values:

`df <- data.frame("ProductID" = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), "Day"=c("Monday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday","Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Friday"), "Amount"=c(5,5,3,7,6,9,5,2), "Product"=c("Food","Food","Food","Food","Toys","Toys","Toys","Toys"), "Store"=c("N","N","W","N", "S","W", "S","S"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .(Amount = sum(Amount, na.rm = TRUE),
              UniqueStores = uniqueN(Store, na.rm = TRUE)), 
          by = .(ProductID, Day, Product)
          ]
```

Output:

```
   ProductID       Day Product Amount UniqueStores
1:         1    Monday    Food     10            1
2:         1   Tuesday    Food     10            2
3:         2 Wednesday    Toys     15            2
4:         2    Friday    Toys      7            1
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the period after by= ?

Comment: I used your solution and but want to use a vector with the column names as argument for by=() instead of writing them all in. Any idea how I could implement that? I'm getting an error regarding the length if I just do by = .(vector_colnames), as if one of the variables had a different amount of rows.

Comment: Just put the name of vector after =

Comment: that didnt work :/ but I solved it using by=eval(vectorname). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

We can do a group by operation in `dplyr` and `summarise` with the `sum` of 'Amount' and `n_distinct` (number of distinct elements of 'Store')

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ProductID, Day, Product) %>%
  summarise(Amount = sum(Amount), 
       UniqueStores = n_distinct(Store), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  ProductID Day       Product Amount UniqueStores
#      <dbl> <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>        <int>
#1         1 Monday    Food        10            1
#2         1 Tuesday   Food        10            2
#3         2 Friday    Toys         7            1
#4         2 Wednesday Toys        15            2
```

---

If there are multiple columns, and want to subset only a part of the columns, while keeping the rest, an option is to `mutate` in the dataset and then use `distinct` to get the first row

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ProductID, Day, Product) %>%
  mutate(Amount = sum(Amount), 
       UniqueStores = n_distinct(Store), .keep = 'all') %>%
  ungroup %>%
  distinct(ProductID, Day, Product, .keep_all = TRUE)
```